# The right way to invalidate view model on time

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

After a bit of research, I haven't found the solution to invalidate and reload view models data on time.

Imagine an application with view model, which is filled with data from the server when initialized, and after some time (let's say, 1 minute), this data gets invalidated and reloaded from the server again.

As I assume, creating dispatcher timer in the view model itself isn't a good idea, because that doesn't feel right to me that view model should be responsible for that kind of things.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChHIWYQ6mIg) video author demonstrates creating dispatcher timer in the view model to update some data after a period of time. That's VB.NET, but it looks very similarly to what I'm trying to achieve.

As I see that now, using the dispatcher in the view model:

```
// ...
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }

    // ...
}

// ...
public interface IDataService
{
    Task<Foo> GetDataAsync();
}

public class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bar;
    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return _bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bar));
        }
    }

    private int _baz;
    public int Baz
    {
        get
        {
            return _baz;
        }
        set
        {
            _baz = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Baz));
        }
    }

    IDataService service;
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    private async void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        await InvalidateAndReloadDataAsync();
    }

    private void InitializeDispatcher()
    {
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    public async Task InvalidateAndReloadDataAsync()
    {
        Foo foo = await service.GetDataAsync();
        Bar = foo.Bar;
        Baz = foo.Baz;
    }

    public FooViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        service = dataService;
        InitializeDispatcher();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()] string name = null)
    {
        if (name != null) PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is it normal to actually use the dispatcher in the view model or there is much better solution?

Comment: why do u need dispatcher timer here? Why cant you use Timers.Timer or Threading.Timer?

Comment: @tym32167 I don't think that it matters, what to choose. I'm guessing is it right to use it in a view model.

Comment: is this timer approach related to your business logic or it is pure UI thing, like animation?

Comment: @tym32167, it is related only to the data, which I'm using for binding in a wpf user control.

Comment: so when you are talking about data - it means view model or model side, not UI side.

Comment: @tym32167, I haven't thought that if I'm talking about view models, there could be questions about the UI part :D

Comment: @tym32167, no, there is nothing about UI side. The view model is used to display (only display, it doesn't accept edits from the user side) the data in control with binding to that data and after some time it should be reloaded/updated. There is nothing else this view model is used for.

Comment: sry, maybe I misunderstood your question. Ok, lets say for this `Is it normal to actually use the dispatcher in the view model` - if you want to check something periodically, its fine to use timer somewhere in your logic. But you dint have to use dispatcher here, you can use simple threading.timer for it.

Comment: I would not be shy about having a viewmodel update itself via a timer it owns. I've done it and didn't regret it. If the viewmodel has UI state that you don't want to lose when the timer fires, I'd break out the timer-dependent data in `FooViewModel` into a child viewmodel class, and replace that on a timer belonging to `FooViewModel`. Note that ordinary INPC properties can safely be updated from out of thread, but ObservableCollection can't. It can only be used or updated in the thread where it was created, so if you've got one, you'll have to invoke into the UI thread to interact with it.

Comment: I prefer a while loop and async. Await task delay the tick time. It's simple, lightweight and just use a property with the while to tell it to stop. If you wanted finer control you could use a storyboard sets a bound property true then false forever. In the vm setter if true then await an async method does your stuff. You can then start stop the storyboard in the view.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you for your comment on updation ObservableCollection. As you wrote, the FooViewModel is already child view model, so that's already done. As tym32167 noted, he would use timers instead of dispatchertimer, but accordingly to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) timers are part of the different thread, so wouldn't be better better to choose DispatcherTimer in this case?

Comment: @vershart Use whatever’s more convenient. DispatcherTimer is fine.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, post your thoughts as an answer, I'll mark it.